# Making websites visible to outside networks with Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, webserver, hosting

I am a new Ubuntu Server user, and I need some assistance in setting it up.

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 64-bit.

**This is my main question**: How can I set up Ubuntu Server to host a website that is visible from networks besides my own?

I have seen and read multiple tutorials on how to set up Ubuntu Server, but all of them show you how to set it up to host websites on a LAN. In the setup processes I have seen, only the standard assigned IP addresses such as 192.168.0.180...have been used.... These processes would work for hosting on a LAN...but, if I go outside of my LAN, the hosted website would probably not be seen by typing in the IP addresses of 192.168.0.180:xxxx....

The computer that will run the server is attached to my home network's router.

How do I configure Ubuntu Server to make the websites that it hosts visible from other outside networks?

If somebody could clue me in on what I'm missing or direct me to a good tutorial on this, I would be very grateful.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Almost completely unrelated to Ubuntu but there you go...

- Forward port 80 to your Ubuntu's internal IP, using your router and [this guide](http://portforward.com).
- Tell Ubuntu to unblock port 80 (might not be needed):

  ```
  sudo ufw allow tcp/80
  ```

By this point people outside your network should be able to put your IP in their browser and see the site. **This won't work internally due to routers' routing restrictions** so don't consider that a fault. Test with something outside the network.

For bonus points (and if your legal IP is dynamic):

- Use a service like [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) to point a domain name at your IP
- CNAME a real domain onto your DynDNS name with a short TTL.
- Make sure the Apache config expects these domains (or you're using a wildcard/default host)
- Set your `/etc/hosts` to shortcut the DNS so it looks locally rather than your legal IP:

  ```
  127.0.0.1    mydomain.com
  ```

If you have a truly static IP assigned to you by your ISP (some residential ISPs still do this), you can just point your domain at it with a long TTL.

Answer (score 0):

Find what kind of router you have, then go to it's IP. It should have something like "Port-forwarding" or "Virtual Firewalls" in the menu. Click on that, and(assuming you use Apache) forward port 80 to the IP of your server.

Should work.